# Inherited dataclass default value override only works if type hints match?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

Having a bizarre issue with dataclasses, where I can't redeclare a default value unless it's type hinted. Am I doing something wrong?

The following example:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Test:
    text:str = "Test"

@dataclass
class Test2(Test):
    text = "Overwritten"

a = Test()
b = Test2()

print(a,b)
```

Outputs this: `Test(text='Test') Test2(text='Test')`

in Test2, I'm trying to change the default value of 'text' to "overwritten" but this doesn't work.

However, the same code with Test2 typehinted works:

```py
@dataclass
class Test2(Test):
    text:str = "Overwritten"
```

Results in `Test(text='Test') Test2(text='Overwritten')`

Am I misunderstanding something? Why does it only let me redefine a default value if I type hint?

Comment: If you don't type-hint then the dataclass decorator *does not recognize it as an instance attribute*, and just assumes it is a class attribute -- check `Test2.text` (which will end up getting shadowed in this case by the instance attribute)

Comment: Note, this isn't bizzare, this is the fundamental principle of the `dataclasses.dataclass` code generator - from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html): "The member variables to use in these generated methods are defined using PEP 526 type annotations."