# Inheritance in Python Dataclasses

Tags: python, inheritance, python-dataclasses

I unknowingly stumbled upon this behaviour of the dataclasses. dataclasses if inherited and overridden in child then it fails to override because of signature mismatch.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class base:
  x: str = "parent"

@dataclass
class child(base):
  x = "child"

config = child()
print(config.x)  # --> parent
```

The reason is the signatures of the variable. if I do other way around.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class base:
  x = "parent"

@dataclass
class child(base):
  x: str = "child"

config = child()
print(config.x)  # --> child
```

I don't know if this is the ideal behaviour or something expected out of dataclasses or is it a bug which needs to be addressed.

Comment: There is an equivalent question which also hasn't been answered yet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72623411/inherited-dataclass-default-value-override-only-works-if-type-hints-match

Answer (score 0):

So my answer is from observation so take it with a grain of salt:

Here is some code I wrote to explain the result

```
@dataclass
class base:
   y: str = "parent"

@dataclass
class child(base):
   x = "child"

config = child()
print(config)
print(config.x)
```

output:

```
child(y='parent')
child
```

As you can see when printing the class out it shows that it has "parent" in the y variable but no x variable with "child". It's important to note [I defined the y's variable type](https://peps.python.org/pep-0526/)

My answer is that you are using a module that requires you to define the type of the variable, so when you don't things start to go "wrong", but my guess is that it is just defaulting back to basic Python class attributes when you don't define it, which the decorator then overwrites with the variable that has had its type defined and understands

EDIT:

Upon further inspection it mentions in documentation, which can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html):

> The member variables to use in these generated methods are defined using PEP 526 type annotations